# foreach loop not behaving as expected javascript ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax

[image]

Need to find out "chacesofrain" for each of the time for the next 14 days

Can only print the chanceofrain for the first day.Not sure how I can get for the rest of the days?

```
[![$('#weather-click').click(function() {
  var state = $('#state')
    .val()
    .trim();

  var country = $('#country')
    .val()
    .trim();

  var queryURL = `http://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/weather.ashx?key=[API_KEY]&q=${state},%20${country}&format=json&num_of_days=14`;

  $.ajax({
    url: queryURL,
    method: 'GET'
  }).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);

    var weather = response.data.weather;
    console.log(weather);
    for (var i = 0; i < weather.length; i++) {
      var hourly = weather[i].hourly;
      console.log(hourly);
      for (var k = 0; k <= hourly.length; k++) {
        var chanceOfRain = hourly[k].chanceofrain;
        console.log(chanceOfRain);
      }

      // setTimeout(function() {
      //   for (var k = 0; k <= hourly.length; k++) {
      //     var changeOfRain = hourly[k].chanceofrain;
      //     console.log(changeOfRain);
      //   }
      // }, 4000);
    }
  });
});][1]][1]
```

I expect chanceofrain for all the days logged in the browser

But the output shows for only 1 day

Comment: what does the error say?

Comment: `weather\[i\].hourly;` what is going on here

Comment: Please fix the code. Paste it again, mark it all, then press Ctrl+K to indent.

Comment: Never mind, you have `var k = 0; k <= hourly.length;`; that's needs to be `k < hourly.length`: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/vc3tsa5p/ (you should probably remove your API key from the question though)

Comment: Thank you Chris. That solved the problem. I would have thought <= should have worked

Comment: Why would you think `<=` would work? Array indexes go from 0 to length-1. If you use `<=`, you try to access `array[array.length]`, which doesn't exist. `for` loops for arrays always use `<`, it's one of the most common idioms. If you have trouble remembering, just use `array.forEach()` instead of writing a loop.

Comment: Notice that you used `< weather.length` correctly. Why do it differently for one array than the other?